# Non integer powers of 10 in algebraic mode in calc

Tags: calc

How should one type numbers like 10^(-2.5) using the 1e... notation in calc using algebraic-mode ? ATM, `1e-2.5` is parsed as (1e-2)*0.5 and indeed evaluates to 5e-3 instead of 3.16e-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use algebraic entry: `'1*10^-2.5`. This is also necessary when using an entry radix of 15 or higher (such as hexadecimal), where `e` is a valid digit.

Comment: I find it nevertheless confusing that the parser should split something like -2.5.